# Overlay box when validation occur at the end of textform field in flutter

Tags: flutter, validation, overlay

I want to show a validation message in a overlay box at the nearest of textformfield . Can you help me? I want like this.[image: This image shows what I want]

Comment: Can you include your code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code using Tooltip Widget hope its help to you refer Tooltip Widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html)

```
 TextFormField(
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Name',
              hintText: 'Card Holder Name',
              suffixIcon: Tooltip(
                message: 'Required',
               
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.info,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Result of your screen [image]

Answer (score 0):

**Result** you can use `errorStyle` to modify

[image]

**Code snippet**

```
 Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  errorText: _isError? " required" : null,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: It is the correct way. But I want like that image.